# Is it possible to set up ipython to tab complete function argument parameters

Tags: python, ipython, tab-completion

In the `ipython` shell, is it possible to set it up so that I can define tab completion for function/method parameters? I have several methods that will only ever take certain arguments from a defined list of potential arguments, and it would be nice if I could tab complete them from inside the list.

If this is possible, how can I set it up? I'd imagine it would be possible *somehow*, given that it's written in python.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not easily, no.

There are ways to extend the possible tab completions, but as far as I know, no simple ways to restrict the list of possible completions.

If you want to try to hack something together, I think this is the place in the code to start looking: https://github.com/ipython/ipython/blob/master/IPython/core/completer.py#L317

Comment: Yeah, I had a feeling it would be something like that. Thanks.

Comment: http://wiki.ipython.org/index.php?title=Cookbook/Custom_completers also gives brief snippet on doing this.